# TypeError: parse is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal

As I had installed the Font Awesome dependencies to my app and tried to run `npm start` right after to test it out, I received this `error` and it has been super brutal & difficult to resolve.

```
$ npm start

> portfolio@0.1.3 start
> react-scripts start

~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/css-select/lib/compile.js:31
        var token = parse(selector, options);
                    ^

TypeError: parse is not a function
    at compileUnsafe (~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/css-select/lib/compile.js:31:14)
    at Function.compile (~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/css-select/lib/compile.js:20:13)
    at new Selector (~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/renderkid/lib/renderKid/styles/rule/Selector.js:13:26)
    at new Rule (~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/renderkid/lib/renderKid/styles/Rule.js:10:21)
    at StyleSheet.module.exports.StyleSheet._setSingleRule (~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/renderkid/lib/renderKid/styles/StyleSheet.js:42:14)
    at StyleSheet.module.exports.StyleSheet._setRule (~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/renderkid/lib/renderKid/styles/StyleSheet.js:33:12)
    at StyleSheet.module.exports.StyleSheet.setRule (~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/renderkid/lib/renderKid/styles/StyleSheet.js:22:14)
    at Styles.module.exports.Styles._setDefaultStyles (~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/renderkid/lib/renderKid/Styles.js:34:25)
    at new Styles (~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/renderkid/lib/renderKid/Styles.js:30:10)
    at RenderKid.module.exports.RenderKid._initStyles (~/Documents/GitHub/REACT/Portfolio/Portfolio/node_modules/renderkid/lib/RenderKid.js:53:27)
```

I've checked my `package.json` file and have my start scripts assigned correctly. I have been at it with this error for nearly a day already.

I have also checked on all my dependencies to make sure they were not outdated. Everything is up to date and still seems to be getting the `error`.

I have even tried to revert back a few steps from my commits but unfortunately still running into this `error` so I believe it has to to something with the `modules`

Comment: @thgaskell how do I remove the `user` text out of the path, I feel like this might have happened after I tried to update my `local` nodejs folder.

Comment: I just removed it from the terminal output for display purposes. But it wouldn't be related to the issue you're running into. It looks like it's an issue with your dependencies. I'd try deleting your `node_modules` folder and reinstalling. Which could be related to if you updated `node` since you last ran the project?

Comment: Yep, you were right. I just tried running `npm start` on a different project and it worked perfectly fine. Will be re-initializing the `node_modules` on my project. Thank you sir

Answer (score -1):

Try to use an older stable version instead of the new version.
It worked for me..
I changed the version in packet.json and removed node_module folder and
then use npm install again